# Cannot read property $valid of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have a form like this -

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
```

There are some fields in the form which I am validating and then submitting the form like this -

```
<input type="button" ng-click="Save(data)" value="Save">
```

In the controller, I want to check if the form is not valid then `Save()` should show some error on the page. For that, I am setting up a watch like this -

```
$scope.$watch('myForm.$valid', function(validity) {
     if(validity == false)
        // show errors
});
```

But I am always getting this error on running it -

```
Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined
```

Can someone explain why?

Thanks

Comment: Should't that be `$scope.myForm.$valid`?

Comment: @MariusBancila nope, it is implicit when you use $watch method.

Comment: Why do you need have a watch method over $valid? you just can check the form on submit.

Comment: I tried that but got the same error. Do i need to use ngSubmit instead?

Answer (score 3):

You just misspelled "myForm" in your controller code. In order to remove the error, Write "myform" instead of "myForm".

However I expect what you want is like this.

```
$scope.Save = function(data){
    alert($scope.myform.$valid);
}
```

I setup [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/cr5n2v2p/).

Comment: I added $watch function at [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/cr5n2v2p/3/). I could see no error. And everything seems to work fine. What is the difference between my fiddle and your code? Would you like to setup your jsfiddle or something which could raise the error you have faced?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was wrapping the form in a modal created in the controller and therefore got the same error. I fixed it with:

HTML

```
<form name="form.editAddress" ng-submit="save()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">Street</label>
        <input name="street" type="text" class="form-control" id="street" placeholder="Street..." ng-model="Address.Street" required ng-minlength="2" />
        <div class="error" ng-show="form.editAddress.street.$invalid">
           <!-- errors... -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save address</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
angular.module("app").controller("addressController", function ($scope, $uibModal, service) {

    $scope.Address = {};
    $scope.form = {};

    $scope.save = function() {
        if (modalInstance !== null) {
            if (isValidForm()) {
                modalInstance.close($scope.Address);
            }
        }
    };

    var isValidForm = function () {
        return $scope.form.editAddress.$valid;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm just confirming this works. I had the same case in my program and this solution worked like a charm. Thanks ...